# Создание онлайн-игры на J2ME SDK

Tags: j2me, java, sdk

Вот решил создать одну онлайн-игру для мобильных телефонов, и желательно трёхмерного изображения. Может кто подскажет литературу и где скачать программу J2ME SDK, а то пытался скачать на java.sun.com, но там не нашёл нужной Jav'ы.

Answer (score 1):

[JAVA ME SDK 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/overview/index.html)
[API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/documentation/index.html) Наверное тоже пригодится =)
А это конкретно уже [api по 3д графике](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/3dgraphics/)